# Is there a prefix notation in Lean?

Tags: operators, lean

In Haskell I can use parentheses to convert an infix operator like `+` into a prefix function so `(+) 2 3` is the same as `2 + 3`. Is there a similar feature in Lean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lean 4 there is the new `·` "this is a placeholder for a function input" notation, so you can do cool things like

```
#check (· + 1)
-- fun a => a + 1
#check (2 - ·)
-- fun a => 2 - a
#eval [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].foldl (·*·) 1
-- 120
```

(these examples from [the manual](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/lean3changes.html)). In Lean 3 you can use the Haskell trick: `#eval (+) 2 3` returns 5.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a regular ASCII period `.` can also be used as an alternative to this Unicode symbol.